# My multiple router outlet link is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular8

I have added `2 router-outlet` in my Angular app and when I am giving the URL for the other `router-outlet`, then the link is showing some error.

This is my **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';
import { FrontpageComponent } from './Mycomponents/frontpage/frontpage.component';
import { RegisterpageComponent } from './Mycomponents/registerpage/registerpage.component';
import { LoginpageComponent } from './Mycomponents/loginpage/loginpage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginpageComponent},
  {path: 'loginpage', component: LoginpageComponent},
  {path: 'registerpage', component: RegisterpageComponent},
  {path: 'frontpage', component: FrontpageComponent, outlet: 'dashboard'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In this, I have added my routing.

This is my **app.component.html**:

```
<div class="main_wrapper">
    <div class="container no_padding">
        <nav>
                <a routerLink="/loginpage" class="mya2">Login</a>
                <a routerLink="/registerpage" class="mya2">Register</a>
                <a [routerLink]="['frontpage']" [skipLocationChange]="true" class="mya2">Other Page</a>
            </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid no_padding">
        <div class="row no_margin">
            <div class="col-md-12 no_padding">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container no_padding">
        <div class="row">
            <router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this, my router outlet name dashboard is not working means the routing `frontpage` is showing the error, incorrect path.

The problem is that when I am clicking on the `a tag with router link frontpage`, it is showing an error.

**Error:**

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'frontpage' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'frontpage'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please check the updated answer where I implemented case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access the secondary router outlet by using (outletname: route)
Example:

```
localhost:4200/loginpage(dashboard:frontpage)
```

**Live Example:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/secondary-router-outlet)

I also implemented your case too. See the Example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-secondary-router-outlet-2)

Comment: Okay, but how to move it on the click like using the router link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has solved my query. Can you please help me in, how to hide the other router-outlet by clicking on the frontpage?

Comment: it would be better if you open a new question for it. Because it is dedicated to this question. whoever come to this question try to find this answer. and your next question is also very important. It should be a separate answer. please tag me so that I can contribute to your next question. Thank you